# Why is 'Segen' reluctant to provide her real name?

Tags: world-war-z

In World War Z, the Israeli soldier that Gerry rescues introduces herself as *Segen*, which I see is simply [Hebrew for the rank of lieutenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Defense_Forces_ranks#Current_ranks). Why is she reluctant to provide her real name?

Is she similarly reticent in the book?

Comment: I don't think it's movie with enough depth to have a real explanation for this. They probably didn't want her to give her first and last name to add to the feeling of haste and lack of time for trifles, and also to make her sound a more badass, and maybe a bit mysterious. Keep in mind that only a minor part of the audience knows what "Segen" means.

Answer (score 8):

You're right about the name "Segen", which is not real name used in Hebrew, but only the rank. I don't know why she wouldn't use her name.

However, I can answer your second question easily - she wasn't, because she doesn't exist in the book. The movie has very little relation to the book, other than taking a global and geopolitical look at a zombie apocalypse. The book is built as a post-apocalypse UN report, not as a personal narrative/adventure of a specific operative.

Answer (score 3):

This may have also been a play on words. In Hebrew is does mean 'Lieutenant' while in German it means 'Blessing'

Mayhap they were giving her some implied history in the name/title that her family may have survived another nasty bit of history?

Comment: Interesting thought, but if it were a play on words, why not expand on it more since she wasn't in the book?

Answer (score -2):

Segen is 7 in Hebrew and blessing in german. And if you know kabbalah the 7 blessings are very important for "correction" or the "apocalypse". Which is in line with this film. So  assume he is suppose to be going to Israel to receive the 7 blessings before attempting to end correction or save the world. I guess putting him  the roll of savior or messiah, if you dare.

So maybe there was a bit of "depth or "meaning" after all. It usually is if you look hard enough for it

Comment: That's not even remotely true. Segen ia nothing like the Hebrew for 7, which is "sheva" or "shiv'a".